# How to retrieve parent key of newly added child from Firebase using java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve "7753400075_Canada_twinpalms_||_twinpalms_20170824001545_F5BA7F33AD51CE283332001BEC409A46" key, How to do so? Here is my code...

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //addListenerForSingleValueEvent
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError arg0) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Object response = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    System.out.println("read data :"+response);
                }
            });
            ref.child("chatmessage").child("devicetoken").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
//                  Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
//                  System.out.println("previousChildName :"+previousChildName);

                    }
                }
});
```

Here is the Firebase database example:

[image: Here is the Firebase database example]

I tried using child data snapshot method but did not worked. It returns all data. But i need to get only the new child added parent. Any help for this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need to filter your results. Assuming that `chatmessage` is a direct child of your Firebase database root, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference deviceTokenRef = rootRef.child("chatmessage").child("devicetoken");
Query query = deviceTokenRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: It returns the "devicetoken" as parent. Didn't return the expected result.

Comment: I have one more question. I have written for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) under onChildAdded and this will executed for all data that exist in my database.Why?

Comment: i just want to get the inserted data, not all data.

Comment: Not from your entire database, just from that particular location. `DataSnapshot` object is a snapshot of a particular location.

Comment: In my case onDataChange function is not executed if something inserted in firebase. Only onChildAdded function is executed.

Comment: That's correct but you only need to use `onDataChange()` method.

Comment: No @Alex Mamo. Lets do private chat

Comment: We are very close. I think we are missing something.

Comment: Ok tell me, what are we missing.

Comment: In my case onDataChange method is executed when i restart the tomcat server and onChildAdded method executed for all data. I did not understand what is happening.

Comment: Using only the code you have shared, it's imposible for me or other users to give a solution. And also this is basically another problem. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question including an [mcv](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you. If you still think that my answer helped you for the initial problem, please reconsider accepting my answer. Thanks!